# React function not returning any value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using firebase to populate a website with a certain user's first and last name, but for some reason it isn't working.

```
getUserName(){
    firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
            // var name = ref.ref('users/' + user.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) => console.log(snapshot.val().displayName));
            var name = user.displayName;
            console.log("name in function: " + name); //prints full name
            return name;
        }
    });
}


render() {
    var name = this.getUserName();
    console.log("name: " + name); //prints undefined
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <h1> Welcome {this.getUserName()} asdfasd </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

These are my two functions. For some reason, when I print out the name variable in both cases, I get two different variables. In getUserName(), it prints out the user's full name, and I then return that value. When the DOM renders, the "name" variable is undefined even though the getUserName() function prints out the full name. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's printed when you do `console.log("name: ", this.getUserName())` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `getUserName()` doesn't actually return anything, so when you try to assign its return value to the `name`-variable, like this `var name = this.getUserName();`, you'll always just set `name` to `undefined`.

As Shailesh Prajapati suggests, you should set the name in the component state. I would even argue, you should separate it out to a global state using something like Redux. Also, you shouldn't call `this.getUserName()` within the `render()` function, as it could (and most likely will) be very bad for performance.

Here's the code, with everything suggested:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.getUserName();
}

getUserName(){
    firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user){
            var name = user.displayName;
            this.setState({ name: name });
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <h1> Welcome {this.state.name} asdfasd </h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have to use State instead of variable.Store name value in `this.SetState({name: value})` and use directly using `this.state.name` where ever you want to use...

Local variable cannot access from outside function so you have to use state in react to access state/variable outside the function..